# ¿Cómo insertar un tipo de dato Geometry en PostgreSQL usando Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, postgis

Tengo que insertar en una tabla `PostgreSQL` un dato `geometry`. Uso `psycopg2` como driver para PostgreSQL. ¿Cómo lo hago??

Este es mi código actual, el cual falla:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO MyTable(id, name, value, location, unit, frecuencyUpdate) VALUES(%(id)s, %(s, %s, ST_SetSRID(%(geom)s::geometry, %(srid)s),%s, %s) RETURNING id;"""

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql, (1,Sensor.city, Sensor.waterState, Sensor.coordinates, 4326 , Sensor.unit, Sensor.frecuencyUpdate))
```

Para obtener el campo `coordinates` uso la librería `geopy`, con lo que es el valor que me devuelve el siguiente código el que quiero almacenar en PostgreSQL+PostGis. Ese campo en la tabla lo tengo definido como `geometry`

```
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode(name)
```

El error que me da es:

> tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El SQL tiene un S mayúscula para el nombre de la tabla pero no se cita, por lo que Postgres está buscando una tabla con letras minúsculas. 
El código correcto para nombrar tablas o campos con mayúsculas es:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO \"Sensor\"(name, value, location, unit, \"frecuencyUpdate\")
                 VALUES(%s, %s, ST_MakePoint(%s, %s),%s, %s)
                 RETURNING id;"""
```